# What is the code for the enclosure link in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

Blogger is heavy with `<data:xxx.xxx/>` styled XHTML, but how do you find the XHTML code for the links you place into the "Enclosure Links" field on the New Posts page?
I haven't tried any yet, but I don't see anything that resembles it neither, scrolling through the source code itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Could be `<data:enclosure.url>`?

Answer (score 2):

To embed “Enclosure Links” value, the conditional tag is `<data:enclosure.url />`.

Comment: Please put in a bit more effort to make your post count! Why, how, references, screenshots. Just so, that it doesn't look like a oneliner.....

Comment: there is no more details about it. The codes i provided is from Blogger / Google. They didn't provided documentation about it also on internet. I just found it randomly from certain default Blogger Template. It was direct to the point of question.